# Send file in color to printer

Tags: printing, printer, cmd.exe, vbscript

I know how to send a file to a printer like this:

```
print /d:\\%COMPUTERNAME%\printer file.bmp
```

However this does not print in color. Is there any way to print in color using the command line (or a programming language)? Perhaps there may be a way using VBScript, but I was unable to find any through google.

Comment: Are you sure that the printer you're sending the file to is a color printer?

Comment: @SolidSnake859 Yes I'm sure :)

Comment: Just curious what does the result look like?

Comment: I don't know of any printer that understands BMP files so, does the print look anything like the image you sent?

Comment: @hdhondt Printers can only understand raw data, and BMP is one of the formats that all printers can accept, without any need for spooling or driver intervention.

Answer (score 0):

On the PC sending the file, is the printer setup to default to color printing? In Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers, right-click the printer, select *Printer properties*, and on the *General* tab, click *Preferences*. Be sure color is default, not gray-scale.

Your printer setup dialog may differ from that below, but should have some means to set color as default.[image: Printer setup dialog]

Comment: Yes, I have checked these settings multiple times, and I know color printing is on because the test page prints in color

Comment: If you are printing from a command prompt, then the Windows driver settings have zero effect. There may be a setting on the printer itself to control this, but that is printer dependent. Try the printer's front panel menu or it's web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Printing from the command prompt is limited; just as [the print command is only able to print ASCII text](http://www.computerhope.com/printhlp.htm), you can only print in monochrome. HOWEVER, I found a [program](http://www.verypdf.com/app/pdf-print-cmd/index.html) that allows you to do print in color from the command line. The downside is that it's a free trial. Here are its commands: http://www.verypdf.com/pdfprint/pdf-print-cmd.html
I sincerely hope this helped!

Comment: VeryPDF only prints PDF files, not BMPs.